# Numeric differences between two different dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to find the numeric difference between two or more columns of two different dataframe.

The following
[image: Table 1]
would be the starting table.
This one Table (Table 2)
[image]

contains the single values that I need to subtract to Table 1.

I would like to get a third table where I get the numeric differences between each row of Table 1 and the single row from Table 2. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please no images of code or data, please show a simple example, what you tried so far and what went wrong plus ideally an expected result. You may refer also to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Be free change `test = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':[15,3,5,2],
         'B':[6,100,0,5],
         'C':[1,0,0,102]})

print (test)


check_string = pd.DataFrame({'Campo':['A','B','C'],
                             'Perc_Valori_Missing':[11.25,99.7,87]})

print (check_string)` like you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df.subtract(df2.values)
```

with `df` being your *starting table* and `df2` being *Table 2*.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and see if this is what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5, 3, 1, 2, 2], 'B':[2, 3, 4, 2, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1], 'B':[2]})
pd.DataFrame(df.values-df2.values, columns=df.columns)
Out: 
   A  B
0  4  0
1  2  1
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just do `df1-df2.values` like below this will use numpy broadcast to substract all df2 from all rows but df2 must have only one row

**example**

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(-1,3), columns="A B C".split())

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(3).reshape(-1,3), columns="A B C".split())

df1-df2.values
```